# require_once でどこまで呼び出すのが常識？

Tags: php, html5

PHP5.6を使ってウェブサイトを作っています。

何回も使うパーツは、require_onceを使って呼び出せばいいということを学びました。
今はヘッダーとフッターを呼び出しているのですが、そこでふと思いました。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> ..........
```

のあたりから全部を呼び出すのは非常識なのでしょうか？

教えて下さい。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

｢body部分で共通出来そうな箇所があったとき、
ヒアドキュメントとしてまとめてしまって良いのだろうか？｣
と解釈していること、私自身のレベルは貴方とさほど差が無いこと
(PHPを使用してWebSite(趣味のもの)を作成しているレベル)を回答前にまずお伝えします。

｢使うことを検討すべき。ただしメンテナンスを考慮した上で｣というのが私の回答です。
メンテナンスが煩雑にならないように、
コンテンツやページの量が多くなった状況での更新作業をイメージして設計されると良いと思います。

Comment: けれん　さん

前提をつけていただけて参考にしやすいです。
ご回答ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

正直なところ、ケースバイケースです。
`<!DOCTYPE html>`
から単純に部品化した場合、どのページにおいても
title
meta description
が同じになってしまいます。
SEOを意識しないのであればあまり関係ないかもしれませんが、titleタグはブラウザでブックマースする際の名前にもなりますので・・・

また、cssとjavascriptの外部ファイルの読込みも共通化してしまいますが、ページの読込み速度などにそれほどセンシティブにならないのであれば、問題ないかもしれません。

上記のような事態を回避するためには、部品を読み込む前にtitleなどを変数に設定しておき、インクルードされる側でその変数を表示するなどの対応が必要です。

あるいは、そのような箇所は部品化せずに、表示部分から部品化することもあります。

ですので、ケースバイケースで、どちらが常識、非常識ということはないと思います。

また、require_onceは複数回同じファイルの読込みを記述しても、最初の一回しか読み込まない、という処理です。
ヘッダやフッタなど、読込みを一回しか記述しないと決まっているものについてはrequire、またはincludeを使ったほうが処理コストが低くて済みますし、プログラムを読む人にも意図が正しく伝わると思います。

Comment: 一回しか読み込まないものについてはというか、複数回読み込む場合では**_onceは使えないですね（二回目以降何も起きなくなる）

Comment: むにゃぐむにゃぐ　さん
ありがとうございます。SEOに関しては意識がありませんでした。
参考になりました。

unarist さん　**_once、覚えておきます。ありがとうございます。